# TFS 2012 builder code coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to set up code coverage in TFS 2012. My solutions builds, My test are run, but I get No code coverage results. I get the follwing error "Code coverage is enabled for the test run. Install Visual Studio on the following build machine to get code coverage results: XXX"
I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional on the build server, but still have the same problem.

Has anyone got any idea of how I can get it working. Do I need a different versionof Visual Studio installing?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do need a different version of Visual Studio.

Code coverage is only available in Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate (in Visual Studio versions 2010 and 2012).